# How to sample points on specific landcover class using Image.stratifiedSample in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, sampling

I need to sample NDVI time series on the crop classe defined in the Copernicus GLDAS Landover dataset (value: 40). The logical approach seems to be using `Image.stratifiedSample` on the landcover, retrieve a `featureCollection` and use it to sample NDVI from another dataset. However I get a `EEException: An internal error has occurred` upon defining the stratified sample with the code below. Can anyone spot what is wrong? Or is there a better approach I haven't seen?

```py
import ee
ee.Initialize()

xmin = -72
xmax = -67
ymin = -42
ymax = -39

ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

coper = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global").first().select('discrete_classification')
coper = coper.clip(ROI)

points = coper.stratifiedSample(
  numPoints=10, 
  classBand='discrete_classification', 
  region=ROI, 
  scale=100,
  classValues=[40]
)

task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(collection=points, fileFormat='GeoJSON')
task.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GEE documnetation, it appears that `classValues` argumnent requires `classPoints` to also be specified. These arguments provide information on the class values for which to override the `numPixels` paramter. To sample exclusively from a single class, I suggest masking your image before calling `Image.stratifiedSample`:

```
points = coper.updateMask(coper.eq(40)).stratifiedSample(
  numPoints=10, 
  classBand='discrete_classification', 
  region=ROI, 
  scale=100
)
```